# Functional groups in graphene oxide

Tags: synthesis

There is already a large number of literature on graphene oxide stating that the number of epoxy groups is quite similar to the number of ethyl groups. However, I was wondering if the number of carboxyl groups attached to the edges of the graphene oxide is either more or less than these groups attached to the basal plane of the graphene oxide. Or does it usually depend on the process of graphene oxide synthesis?

I am only looking into the perspective of these three major functional groups present in graphene oxide. Although, I know that many functional groups can be present in graphene oxide.

Comment: I think it all depends.